# How do I connect from Azure Data Factory to an AWS-hosted Postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Postgres database created on Heroku but looks like it's spun up on AWS based on the server name. Unfortunately, I can't tell if it's an Aurora or RDS instance.

I'm trying to create some data pipelines on Azure Data Factory to do some ETL work moving Blob files onto the Postgres Database but am having a tough time setting it up. The default Postgres option isn't working - looks like DataFactory tries to make a JDBC connection.

I'm stuck and am clueless as to how I should set up the connection.